# How to write spark-scala tests available to run/connect to a hadoop cluster?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scalatest

I am creating Tests for spark/scala process  to write unit test cases (like Junits). I have an ETL process which connects to Hbase tables which are present on hadoop cluster and process and writes the data into another hbase tables In this process the challenge is the program needs to connect to a cluster instead of running from local. Could you please suggest a solution or an approach to handle this scenario to be able to run test against by connect with hbase which is on cluster?

```
import com.mymmodels.myDocument

import scala.io.Source
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, BeforeAndAfterEach, FunSuite}

class myServiceTest extends FunSuite{

  test("Test sample method") {
    //assert(true === myxmlservice.IsDataAvailableInMyDataJson)
    val rawXml = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/my_raw.xml")).mkString
    val imyDocument:myDocument = mymxmlparser.parsemyGoldenXml(rawDataXml)
    assert("1" === myDocument.entity_id)
    assert("N" === myDocument.isDeleted)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use dockerized approach, ie use docker images for each component in your pipeline and orchestrate them with docker-compose for test runs. There are docker images for most of the Hadoop-related products.